# Repositioning element on hover, ends up under Bootstrap well

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown menu item:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown"><i class='far fa-calendar-alt fa-fw sidebarIcon'></i>Planning <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu level1">
        <li><a href="../gus/indexBacklog.php"><i class='fas fa-history fa-fw sidebarIcon'></i>Backlogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="../gus/"><i class='far fa-clock fa-fw sidebarIcon'></i>Schedules</a></li>
        <li><a href="../tasks/"><i class='far fa-check-square fa-fw sidebarIcon'></i>Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'd like it to auto-expand & shift to the right when you hover over it.
So far I have this jQuery code working:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.level1').parent().css({position: 'relative'});
    $(this).find('.level1').css({top: 0, left: 100, position:'absolute', zIndex: 1000});
    $(this).find('.level1').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.level1').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(200);
});
```

But the problem is, it ends up under the Bootstrap Well in the next column over. The zIndex set to 1000 does't seem to have any effect on it. Any suggestions on how to get it above the Well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to your z-index.

```
$(this).find('.level1').style('zIndex', 1000, 'important');
```